# ThemeChanger in GWT-Ext

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-ext

I'm using GWT 2.0, GWT-Ext 1.5 & Java 1.6 with Mozilla 3.6.x.

I'm trying to implement ThemeChanger module as per this [link](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-ext/source/browse/trunk/samples/showcase2/src/com/gwtext/sample/showcase2/client/ThemeChanger.java). But I'm not able to achieve it. Can anyone look at my code & tell me what am I missing or doing wrong?

**Test.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="ThemeTest.css">
    <link id="theme" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/resources/themes/green/css/xtheme-green.css"/> 
    <link id="theme" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/resources/themes/red/css/xtheme-red.css"/> 
    <link id="theme" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/resources/themes/gray/css/xtheme-gray.css"/> 
    <link id="theme" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=""/> 

    <title>Web Application Project</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="themetest/themetest.nocache.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <iframe src="javascript:''" id="__gwt_historyFrame" tabIndex='-1' style="position:absolute;width:0;height:0;border:0"></iframe>

    <noscript>
      <div style="width: 22em; position: absolute; left: 50%; margin-left: -11em; color: red; background-color: white; border: 1px solid red; padding: 4px; font-family: sans-serif">
        Your web browser must have JavaScript enabled
        in order for this application to display correctly.
      </div>
    </noscript>


  </body>
</html>
```

**Test.gwt.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module rename-to='test'>
    <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>
    <inherits name='com.gwtext.GwtExt' />

    <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard'/>

    <stylesheet src="resources/css/ext-all.css" />
    <stylesheet src="resources/css/style.css" />
    <script src="adapter/ext/ext-base.js" />
    <script src="ext-all.js" />

    <entry-point class='com.test.client.ThemeTest'/>

    <source path='client'/>
    <source path='shared'/>

</module>
```

**EntryPointClass: ThemeTest.java**

```
@Override
    public void onModuleLoad() {
        FormPanel formPanel = new FormPanel();
        formPanel.setTitle("Form");

        TextField nameField = new TextField("Name");
        TextField descField = new TextField("Desc");

        formPanel.add(nameField);
        formPanel.add(descField);
        formPanel.add(new ThemeChanger());
        RootPanel.get().add(formPanel);
    }
```

**ThemeChanger.java**

```
public class ThemeChanger extends ComboBox {

    public ThemeChanger() {

            final Store store = new SimpleStore(new String[]{"theme", "label"}, new Object[][]{
                            new Object[]{"/public/resources/themes/green/css/xtheme-green.css", "Green"},
                            new Object[]{"", "Aero Glass"},
                            new Object[]{"/public/resources/themes/red/css/xtheme-red.css", "Red"},
                            new Object[]{"/public/resources/themes/gray/css/xtheme-gray.css", "Gray"},
            });
            store.load();

            setFieldLabel("Select Theme");
            setEditable(false);
            setStore(store);
            setDisplayField("label");
            setForceSelection(true);
            setTriggerAction(ComboBox.ALL);
            setValue("Gray");
            setFieldLabel("Switch theme");
            addListener(new ComboBoxListenerAdapter() {
                    public void onSelect(ComboBox comboBox, Record record, int index) {
                            try {
                                String theme = record.getAsString("theme");
                                CSS.swapStyleSheet("theme", theme);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                    }
            });
            setWidth(100);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide the current status of the application ? Is it displaying any output or throwing any errors in back end

Answer (score 1):

Check your locations of themes.

You can download gxt-2.2.1.zip. 
Extract it on your computer. there will be a directory named `resources` containing themes
which you need to copy at your project location.

I have checked your code by palcing below example values

```
new Object[]{"/test/resources/themes/slate/css/xtheme-slate.css", "Slate"},
new Object[]{"/test/resources/themes/access/css/xtheme-access.css", "Access"},
```

In `ThemeChanger` classs with themes given in above .jar

It worked.