# Changing GWT theme Dynamically

Tags: css, gwt

I have a GWT application,
I created appBlueTheme.jar,appOrangeTheme.jar and added to BuildPath of project.
My module.gwt.xml file has

```
 ....
<inherits name='appBlueTheme.appBlueTheme'/>
<inherits name='appOrangeTheme.appOrangeTheme'/>
 ...
```

But in my app i see the effect of appBlueTheme as GWT doc say

"inherited modules will be cascaded in the order they are listed"

I want theme to be changed based on user response.
How do i achieve this?

Comment: Take a look at this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5603880/themechanger-in-gwt-ext

Comment: This question is closed by mistake. The suggested duplicate deals with a different framework - GWT-Ext.

Comment: @AndreiVolgin GWT-Ext framework is used only to take user input for selection of theme. The main logic "dynamic theme change" is done using GWT only.

Comment: That question is about GXT (in the title and tags). It has no accepted answers, and the only answer provided is specific to GXT.  How does it make it a duplicate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by "theme" you mean styling, the right approach is not to create a separate jar for each theme, but to use CSS instead.

A. If you use CSSResource, you can use conditional CSS:

https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle#Conditional_CSS

B. If you use an external CSS file, instead of

```
.headerPanel {
    background: blue;
}
```

you can specify a different background based on a theme selected:

```
.orangeTheme .headerPanel {
    background: orange;
}
.blueTheme .headerPanel {
    background: blue;
}
```

Note that your code (or Ui:Binder) should only assign class "headerPanel" to a widget. When you start your app, you assign a default theme to your outmost widget (the one you add to the RootPanel). For example, you set

```
myAppPanel.addStyleName("blueTheme");
```

This will give a blue background to all widgets with "headerPanel" class. When a user chooses a different theme, you remove "blueTheme" class and add "orangeTheme" class. It will automatically refresh the page (no need to reload it) and all styles will change.

EDIT:

If you need to apply a theme to the entire app, including PopupPanel and dialogs, use this code to apply your theme:

```
Document.get().getBody().setClassName("blueTheme");
```

Comment: Approach B should work without a page refresh, shouldn't it? Going `myAppPanel.removeStyleName("blueTheme"); myAppPanel.addStyleName("orangeTheme");` should trigger an app-wide re-rendering of DOM elements (haven't tried myself).

Comment: Excellent catch. I did not mean to say "reload" the page. I edited the answer to make it clear.